# boost:bind self-pointing pointer

Tags: ros, compile, boost, actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm writing a test program about actionlib. Referencing the wiki document of SimpleActionServer. However, I makes a error because of this instruction.

```
Server server(n, "do_dishes", boost::bind(&execute, _1, &server), false);
```

The variable **server** is used before it's allocated as **server**. Is that possible? At least, my visual studio 2010 compiler doesn't understand that style of code. Please help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/156016/boost:bind-self-pointing-pointer/) by [Younghyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/14156/younghyo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The code example on the wiki page seems to be wrong.

If you look at [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionServer%28ExecuteCallbackMethod%29) you see that the placeholder for the callback arguments `_1` has to be after the pointer to the object.

Does this solve your problem?

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Younghyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/14156/younghyo/) on 2014-04-22**:
I saw the tutorial you suggested already. In there, they uses a wrapping class. it works. (with a warning). but i want to do this by not making additional class. i also asked this strange syntax question to stackoverflow.com. i finally notified that MSVC cannot build it while G++ can do it.